# How to get rank in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

In my Laravel 5.3 app, votes table has a net votes column. I'd like to find the video's rank according to net votes. I'd like to display the rank like below list. I know sql @raw method. but, I want to use Laravel method. because, there are some other tables jointed with this user table and some other shorting also need to be done.

video table:

```
id     | net_votes| video_id | 
------ | -------: |:-------: |
1      |    5     |   1      |   
2      |    11    |   2      |   
3      |    3     |   1      |    
4      |    6     |   3      |    
5      |    5     |   2      |
```

I want to get results like this

```
id     | net_votes| rank
------ | -------: |:----:
2      |    11    |   1
4      |    6     |   2
1      |    5     |   3
5      |    5     |   4
3      |    3     |   5
```

I am using this code now. its working. but I want to use Laravel Eloquent Method.

```
$score_board_list = DB::select("SELECT *, total, @r:=@r+1 as rank,
           @l:=total FROM ( select username, first_name, video_title, 
           net_votes, sum(net_votes) as total from videos
           LEFT JOIN users ON videos.user_id = users.id
           LEFT JOIN profile ON users.id = profile.user_id
           group by videos.id order by total desc, videos.created_at desc ) totals, (SELECT @r:=0, @l:=NULL) rank");
```

Comment: **user's rank according to net votes** --> you could order them in decreasing order by **net votes** voila, you got your first rank, second, etc.. well, at least, gave us an example of what you've tried.. also ** joined with this user table** is pretty interesting, if you consider it as crucial, post it also.. as detailed as possible

Comment: @BagusTesa I have edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: you mean you wnted to use laravel query builder?

Comment: yes. @NewbeeDev

Comment: You should research about MVC and Eloquent. No sense in having Laravel 5.3 and doing raw queries like that...

Comment: @TomasButeler Eloquent doesn't support things like MySQL Variables which are required to calculate rankings, Eloquent is focused on being agnostic of very specific database engines, it provides the most common features, but for anything specific you need to use `DB::raw()`, that's why that method exists.
You could calculate the rankings in PHP but then you get into problems because of large datasets and pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that

Stored your subquery into a variable

```
$subquery = "( 
     SELECT    username, 
               first_name, 
               video_title, 
               net_votes, 
               Sum(net_votes) AS total 
     FROM      videos 
     LEFT JOIN users 
     ON        videos.user_id = users.id 
     LEFT JOIN profile 
     ON        users.id = profile.user_id 
     GROUP BY  videos.id 
     ORDER BY  total DESC, 
               videos.created_at DESC ) totals";
```

then equivalent for

```
Select * from (subquery)
```

into Eloquent is

```
DB::table(DB::raw('subquery'))
```

then to select a custom column

```
// for example  
->select(DB::raw('@r:=@r+1 as rank'))
```

So your query builder would be like this

```
$subquery = "( 
     SELECT    username, 
               first_name, 
               video_title, 
               net_votes, 
               Sum(net_votes) AS total 
     FROM      videos 
     LEFT JOIN users 
     ON        videos.user_id = users.id 
     LEFT JOIN profile 
     ON        users.id = profile.user_id 
     GROUP BY  videos.id 
     ORDER BY  total DESC, 
               videos.created_at DESC ) totals";


$score_board_list = DB::table(DB::raw($subquery))
->select(
    '*', 
    'total', 
    DB::raw('@r:=@r+1 as rank'), 
    DB::raw('@l:=total'))
->get();
```